Экранировать символ @ в шаблонизаторе blade Laravel
Пробую подключить в view-шках js файл с cdn, который в путях содержит символ @.
@push('scripts')
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@json-editor/json-editor@latest/dist/jsoneditor.min.js"></script>
@endpush

Как результат - ругается
Пробую такой вариант
@push('scripts')
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@@json-editor/json-editor@@latest/dist/jsoneditor.min.js"></script>
    @endpush

Ругаться перестает, однако и файл не подключает.

Можете попробовать так:
<script src="{{ url('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@json-editor/json-editor@latest/dist/jsoneditor.min.js') }}"></script>


пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
